# LINQ anonymous type to object()

Tags: vb.net, linq, anonymous-types

I have this query, which works as expected:

```
Dim test = result.GroupBy(Function(row) groupedindexes.Select(
                              Function(grpindex) row(grpindex)).ToArray, comp).
                      Select(Function(g) New With {g.Key, Key .sumOff4 = g.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x(3)))})
```

The `g.Key` is like this: a, b, c, the `.sumOff4` is a simple number.

Now I would like to have a `IEnumerable(Of Object())` or a `List(Of Object())` to have an output like this: a, b, c, 10.

I have tried with ToList, ToArray, etc., but not get the right result.

Basically, I would like to show the data in a gridview, where `g.Key.Count` may vary, like this:

```
dgv.Columns.Add("f1", "f1")
dgv.Columns.Add("f2", "f2")
dgv.Columns.Add("f3", "f3")
dgv.Columns.Add("f4", "f4")
For Each item In test
    dgv.Rows.Add(item)
Next
```

But I get the key and the sum in one column:

[image]

I would like to have the values in the 4 coluns. How can I do this?

EDIT:

In the meantime, I figured it out. I created a helper class:

```
Partial Class groupedresult
    Private _keys As Object()
    Private _aggr_values As New List(Of Object)
    Public Sub New(ByVal keys As Object(), ByVal ParamArray aggr_values() As Object)
        _keys = keys
        For i = 0 To aggr_values.Count - 1
            _aggr_values.Add(aggr_values(i))
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Property keys As Object()
        Get
            Return _keys
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object())
            _keys = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property aggregated_values As List(Of Object)
        Get
            Return _aggr_values
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Object))
            _aggr_values = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

and changed the query like this:

```
Dim test = result.GroupBy(Function(row) groupedindexes.Select(
                              Function(grpindex) row(grpindex)).ToArray, comp).
                      Select(Function(g) New groupedresult(g.Key, g.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x(3)))))
```

And then I coded this:

```
Dim objects As New List(Of Object)
Dim lst As New List(Of Object())
For Each item In test
    objects.AddRange(item.keys)
    objects.AddRange(item.aggregated_values)
    lst.Add(objects.ToArray)
    objects.Clear()
Next
```

And then I could write:

```
For Each item In lst
    dgv.Rows.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: Where is `10` coming from? And is it always 4 columns?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is exactly what you're looking for,
but it may assist in guiding you the the solution.

From what I understand,
You have LINQ query, that on a single collection works fine,
and on a collection of that object doesn't work as you expect.

When projecting on a collection of collection,
You can use SelectMany for the use you describe.

Code Sample:

```
Dim strings = New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "E", "E", "A", "B", "E"}

Dim groupedStrings = strings.
    GroupBy(Function(o) o).
    Select(Function(o) New With {.Key = o.Key, .Count = o.Count}).
    ToList()

Dim stringsCollection = New List(Of List(Of String)) From {
    New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "E", "E", "A", "B", "E"},
    New List(Of String) From {"B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "E"},
    New List(Of String) From {"A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"}
}

Dim groupedStringsFromCollection = stringsCollection.
    SelectMany(Function(o) o).
    GroupBy(Function(o) o).
    Select(Function(o) New With {.Key = o.Key, .Count = o.Count}).
    ToList()
```

Hope this helps.